# ABC is an isosceles triangle. If the coordinates of the Base are B(1,3) and C(-2,7), then the coordinates of A will be

Tags: coordinate-systems

Using the simple distance formula 
$$(x-1)^2+(y-3)^2=(x+2)^2+(y-7)^2$$
$$6x-8y+43=0$$
Obviously, the point will lie on this line. However, is it possible to find the exact the coordinates of A? Can this question be meaningfully solved?

Comment: The question is obviously missing something . All points on $6x-8y+43 = 0$ satisfies the condition except $(x,y) = (-0.5,5)$

Comment: Any point on that line would form an isosceles triangle.

Comment: Is it necessary that AB=AC. With either B or C  as center and BC as radius if you draw a circle any point on that will be point A where either AB=BC or AC = BC. Exclude points when A, B ,C become collinear.

Comment: Why doesn't 0.5, 5 count?

Comment: Because then $ABC$ forms a staright line.

Answer (score 0):

Find the line that goes through points B and C and then find the line perpendicular to this line that passes through the mid-point of line BC. Then any point on this perpendicular line (A) will form and isosceles triangle with ABC (except when it's the mid-point of BC since it's obviously a line there).